# How to prevent Outlook AppointmentItem from being marked as unsaved

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

To create a new AppointmentItem I am using the following code

```
        var item = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);

        item.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
        item.Start = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0).AddMinutes(DateTime.Now.Minute % 30 == 0 ? 0 : 30 - DateTime.Now.Minute % 30);
        item.Duration = 30;

        item.Display(false);
```

When the item is first created the Saved property is True, however after adding some initial custom properties the Saved property is False.

Is there a better way to accomplish setting init properties to an object so that Outlook treats it like it's a Saved object without actually saving the object? (I don't want to have the AppointmentItem saved in case the user opens a new appointment and closes it without changing anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect that other changes were made using the PropertyChange event, but when Display is called, there is no way to convince Outlook that the item does not need to be saved until it is actually saved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up adding a property change event (to check for events after the data was initialized). Then I added an event on item close to check to see if the item was changed, if so continue as normal, if not then discard the changes.